# Vulnerability scanners for web APIs

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, api

I've built a few web APIs for my company at intellectstorm.com and I'm tasked to test these products by scanning for vulnerabilities. I can't decide on a good tool as yet; so far I've used the following:

1. Barracuda Vulnerability Scanner
2. Nessus
3. Openvas
4. Nikto

I can't continue using Nessus or Barracuda because they're not open source.
These tools are powerful, but I think they're used for front-end application testing. I did not see any documentation of finding web APIs and scanning for vulnerabilities for web APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Burpsuite has the capability. You first set up your client to proxy traffic through Burp, then you can start testing the API.

Step by step here: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2898216-using-burp-to-test-a-rest-api